# In Adobe Acrobat 11 how do I use a font present in a pdf document but grayed out in the application font list?

Tags: pdf, fonts, adobe-acrobat

I am using Adobe Acrobat 11.0.0. I have opened a pdf document I received from someone. The document has some text in the `Helvetica Neue LT Std` font. I would like to modify that text. The choose `Edit | Edit Text & Images` from the drop-down menu. The result is that I can click inside a text box, and when I do so I see the `Helvetica Neue LT Std` font show up in the font menu. The problem is that when I type a character, the font in such font menu on the right changes to something else such as plain `Helvetica` or `Minion Pro`. The `Helvetica Neue LT Std` appears on the menu at the bottom of the list separated by a horizontal line. But I cannot select it because it is grayed out.

How can I make edits and use the `Helvetica Neue LT Std` font (presumably without having to pay for the font)?

---

NOTE: I've read [this article](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/pdf-fonts.html#preview_pdfs_without_local_fonts) but didn't find it helpful.

Comment: You can't.  While you the author embedded the font that was for the purpose of viewing the content in the font.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have Helvetica Neue LT Std installed on your system, you can not edit text set in that font. The font is embedded, and subsetted, which means that it only contains the characters actually present in the document.

Acrobat 11.0.0 is a dot-null version, and should be updated to the newest one. However, its editing capabilities are rather weak, and if editing text is an issue, I strongly suggest to upgrade to Acrobat DC, whose text editing capabilities are far superior to the ones of Acrobat XI.